# Firebase deploy errors starting with non-zero exit code

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

devs, I'm trying to deploy a simple cloud function to the firebase console, everything working very well (installation of npm & configuration & other stuff...).

then I wrote a simple function in the **index.js** file :

```
'use strict'
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification  = functions.database.ref('/notififcation/{user_id}/{notififcation_id}').onWrite(

event =>
       {
    const user_id = event.params.user_id;
    const notififcation_id = event.params.notififcation_id;
    console.log('this id is the ' , user_id);
    
       }
):
```

then, when I wanna deploy it to firebase with this command **firebase deploy**, This error keeps appearing,
this is the error :

---

```
C:\Users\nasro\Desktop\oussamaproject\notifyfun\functions\index.js
  14:2  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token :

? 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional l
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nasro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-19T21_28_2
892Z-debug.log
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "C:\Users\nasro\Desktop\oussamaproject\notifyfun\fun
ions" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\nasro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase
ools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\nasro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-
ols\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\nasro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\f
ebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:2

    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\nasro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\f
ebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:3

    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "C:\\Users\\nasro\\Desktop\\oussamaproject\\not
yfun\\functions" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "C:\\Users\\nasro\\Desktop\\oussamaproject\\notifyfun\\f
ctions" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

so after searching for a solution in firebase documentation and articles, I tried those solutions

**solution one:**
in **firebase.json** by default:

```
"predeploy": [
  "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
]
```

i Modified it to:

```
"predeploy": [
  "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
]
```

the error keeps appearing again with the same error message, so I tried solution 2

**Solution two**

I modified again the file **firebase.json** to :

```
"predeploy": [
         "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint",
         "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build"
    ]
```

and the error keeps appearing again and again with the same error message (**btw** I'm using windows7)

So any solution or suggestions for this error ..

Answer (score 0):

the `onWrite` method takes 2 arguments - `change` and `context` and the params live on the `context` object.

could you try the following:

```js
functions.database.ref("/notififcation/{user_id}/{notififcation_id}").onWrite((change, context)=>{
    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notififcation_id = context.params.notififcation_id;
    console.log("this id is the " , user_id);

    return null; // <----- please try returning something as well at the end
});
```

More info here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value

There also seems to be an issue with the linting hence the linting errors are coming up as per your comment below, perhaps try updating your `.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.json` file in your project like so:

```js
module.exports = { 
  root: true, 
  env: { es6: true, node: true, }, 
  extends: [ "eslint:recommended" ], // <--- remove google from here
  rules: { quotes: ["error", "double"], }
};
```

Comment: I literally copy-paste your code, the only thing that changed was the message error :

the old error + this new part :

Comment: @Nặśř'Eddíŋě could you please also try returning something from the function too, so it can close itself out. have updated my answer above to reflect the same

Comment: 1:1   error  Strings must use doublequote                           quotes
   1:13  error  Missing semicolon                                      semi
   3:23  error  Strings must use doublequote                           quotes
   6:1   error  This line has a length of 98. Maximum allowed is 80    max-len
   6:24  error  Strings must use doublequote                           quotes
   7:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4           indent
   7:11  error  Identifier 'user_id' is not in camel case              camelcas

 ...

Comment: okay i will check it

Comment: @Nặśř'Eddíŋě From the error you pasted, it seems like google is throwing some linting errors like an eslint error, could you please also check on the lint config as well in the `.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.json` file

Comment: to be honest with you, I'm not familiar with those types of linting errors
any source or articles or .. can help me to handle this subject

Comment: @Nặśř'Eddíŋě do you have an `.eslint.js` file in your project, if you do, could you please share it, happy to help

Comment: there is one named .eslintrc.js , and it contains :
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};

Comment: @Nặśř'Eddíŋě could you try removing google stuff from `extends` prop in the lint configuration so it becomes like this - `module.exports = { root: true, env: { es6: true, node: true, }, extends: [ "eslint:recommended" ], rules: { quotes: ["error", "double"], }, };`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your function ends with a colon instead of a semicolon. Change it to be like this:

```ts
"use strict";
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database
    .ref("/notififcation/{user_id}/{notififcation_id}")
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      const userId = context.params.user_id;
      // const notififcationId = context.params.notififcation_id;
      console.log("this id is the ", userId);
    }
    );
```

Comment: No, it wasn't the problem

Comment: @Nặśř'Eddíŋě can you show the new error that is being thrown?

Comment: it's too long, I will divide it into parts :
   1:1   error  Strings must use doublequote                           quotes
   1:13  error  Missing semicolon                                      semi
   3:23  error  Strings must use doublequote                           quotes
   6:1   error  This line has a length of 98. Maximum allowed is 80    max-len
6:24  error  Strings must use doublequote                           quotes
   7:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4           indent
   7:11  error  Identifier 'user_id' is not in camel case              camelcas

Comment: 8:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4           indent
   8:11  error  Identifier 'notififcation_id' is not in camel case     camelcas

   8:11  error  'notififcation_id' is assigned a value but never used  no-unuse
-vars
   9:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4           indent
   9:17  error  Strings must use doublequote                           quotes
   9:35  error  There should be no space before ','                    com

Comment: cing
  10:4   error  Newline required at end of file but not found          eol-last
..
..
_____
then the old error appearing again (after this new part)

Comment: @Nặśř'Eddíŋě those errors are because you initialized your functions with eslint, which is enforcing strict formatting. I've updated my answer to comply with the errors being thrown. You can also click on the errors one by one and it will take you to the line number that needs reformatting

Comment: is there any other way to avoid this ** strict formatting**, cuz it makes my life so hard

Comment: @Nặśř'Eddíŋě run `firebase functions init` again and when it asks if you want eslint, say no.